# Having some SQL subquery issues with taking query result from one query and using it to filter the next result

Tags: mysql

Having some SQL subquery issues with taking query result from one query and using it to filter the next result

Table one I took the results from query one  but i want to use the result from fav to  filter from  my teams table where i have many teams and it will display the results

```
mysql> SELECT fav FROM login WHERE username ='djk';
+-------------+
| fav         |
+-------------+
| Real Madrid |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

i tried this

```
(SELECT fav FROM login WHERE username ='djk') as team_name  from team;
```

and many other have not worked

this is my team table so i want to use the results from the one query to filter from team_name and only show the requested team

```
mysql> describe team ;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| team_id     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| team_name   | varchar(355) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| stadium     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| coach       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| league_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| league_id   | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If some one could guide me in the right direction i would appropriate it.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do? You want to display team stats based on the user column `fav`'s value? You don't need a subquery for this, use a `join`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple subquery in the `WHERE` clause should work just fine:

`SELECT * FROM team WHERE team_name = (SELECT fav FROM login WHERE username = 'djk'`

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is an [inner join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
select *
from team t
join login l on t.team_name = l.fav
where l.username ='djk';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks for the help  i was able to do it with where

<?php
ob_start();
echo $_SESSION['username'] ;
$getname = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

                            $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
                                echo "here";
}
                    $sql3 = "SELECT * from team where team_name =(select fav from login where username='${getname}')";
```